# How do I move the window menu to the window title bar in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, window, settings, titlebar

I use multiple monitors so having the window menu move to the top bar now I've finally upgraded to 18.04 is not good for me because it moves the window menu options a long way away from the window.

I'd like my window menu options associated with the window, not the screen.
[image]
I've searched the settings, tried gnome tweaks and googled to no avail.

In old Ubuntu versions, I reset this using the settings under appearance|behaviour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that using **(GNOME) Tweaks** (previously known as *(GNOME) Tweak Tool*). First install it if it's not installed by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

(or `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`).

Then launch Tweaks, go to "*Top Bar*" section and toggle **off** the "Application Menu" option.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it has been deleted. I'm using Fedora 31 + GNOME 3.34, and this switch isn't in tweak anymore.

Comment: Yeah, the 'application menu' feature should be removed from some recent GNOME versions: https://blogs.gnome.org/aday/2018/10/09/farewell-application-menus/

Comment: Thank you! I've received the same answer in the GNOME subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/ea3xkn/appmenu_in_the_key_orggnomedesktopwmpreferences/

Comment: Could make the application menu disappear from the main bar. but the window itself does not have the menu?

Comment: @GeneCode All the application-related options, preferences etc. should be found in the window itself now.

Comment: I am using 18.04 still. So no.

Comment: @GeneCode The answer was written specifically for 18.04. Once you make the application menu disappear from the main top bar following this answer, the menu appears under a new icon in the application window titlebar (notice the GNOME "footprint" icon at the left of search/magnifying-glass icon).